# Hide desktop.ini in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

My Google Drive folders are cluttered with `desktop.ini`files (which are usually hidden in all other folders).

1. Why is the Windows system file `dekstop.ini` not hidden in the Windows Explorer in my Google Drive folder?
2. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are used to make the Windows Explorer display customized icons for each folder (like the green check marks to indicate that the folder has synced). There doesn't seem to be a way to disable this functionality, but you can hide them by turning off the "show hidden files and folders" setting in the File Explorer options under the View tab.